# How to modify the producer cache properties for Spring Pulsar 0.2.0 producer?

Tags: apache-pulsar, spring-pulsar

Spring Pulsar 0.2.0

how to modify ProducerConfigProperties.cache parameter

i want to change cache properties through application.properties, such as:

```
spring.pulsar.producer.cache.expire-after-access=600s
spring.pulsar.producer.cache.maximum-size=1000
spring.pulsar.producer.cache.initial-capacity=5
```

but, ProducerConfigProperties dont have setCache method

Is there any other way to modify this parameter？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the properties in the `application.properties` (or application.yml)  will set the underlying cache values. Are you not seeing the values being set?

The reason there is no "setCache" is because we use [JavaBeans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.java-bean-binding) property bindings. There is no `setCache()` method but instead a `getCache().setXyz()`. However, if you are trying to set the fields on the `ProducerConfigProperties` object, it is probably already too late in the lifecycle. The recommended way to set these is via application.properties.

Comment: My fault. In fact, I am using the application.properties configuration parameters, but I have used the wrong path to cause the parameters not effect